# SQL Server append table to an existing table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-update, union, alter-table

I need to append rows from one table to an existing table. I am thinking something like following but this gives an error

```
select * 
into table1
from (select * 
      from table1
      union
      select *  
      from table2) as tmp
```

Is there a way to use `ALTER TABLE` or `UPDATE` with `UNION`?

Comment: table 1 and table 2 structure is equal?

Comment: Something is terribly wrong with your database and your approach when you intentionally duplicate an existing set of rows and when you have multiple tables with the same structure (and possibly very similar names).  The short answer is you can't insert rows into an existing table using the "select ... into ..." statement. You have an answer, but it does not address the larger issues - you should be concerned.

Answer (score 7):

i will assume the below scenario ,

1- you need to insert in table1 all data from table 2
use this one

```
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 (Col1, Col2)
 SELECT Col1, COl2  FROM  Table2
```

2- you have 2 tables , table 1 and need to insert in table 3

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3 (Col1, Col2)
SELECT  Col1, COl2  FROM Table1
Union all --to remove duplication in data 
SELECT  Col1, COl2  FROM Table2
```

Answer (score 2):

Just do a direct insert to Table1 from Table2

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (Col1, Col2)
    SELECT
        Col1, COl2
    FROM 
        Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
   -- merge table1 and table2 data in temp table
    SELECT * INTO #Temp
      FROM 
          (
            SELECT * 
              FROM table1
             UNION
            SELECT *  
              FROM table2
          )

    -- empty table1 and delete existing data
    TRUNCATE TABLE table1

    -- insert all merged data in table 1
    INSERT INTO table1 
                SELECT *
                  FROM #Temp
```

> You can remove **duplicate rows** with using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`